# Unit conversions with Janskys

Tags: physics, units-of-measurement, astronomy

I'm not sure how to go about converting these units.

What I know...
1Jy = 10^-26 W/m^2 Hz = 10^-23 ergs/cm^2 s Hz

What I don't know...
1Jy = ? W/m^2 nm = ? ergs/cm^2 s Å

The units just don't seem to work even bringing in speed of light.

One example of where this is used can be found [here](http://astro.pas.rochester.edu/~aquillen/ast142/costanti.html) where the 'zero flux (Jy)' column is in Janskys and the 'zero flux' column is in ergs/cm^2 s Å. There is not a single constant that can convert all of these pairs.

Is this conversion not even possible? W/m^2 nm to ergs/cm^2 s Å is simple but to get it in Jy might not be feasible.

Comment: Converting bandwidth between frequency and wavelength is not just a unit conversion you can do by multiplying by a constant conversion factor. If I can find time later I'll post an Answer (if nobody beats me to it).

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm stumped. By my reckoning there should be a wavelength^2 factor, but when I use "effective wavelength", my results are *way* off.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good explanation [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=UC_1_804BXgC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=converting%20bandwidth%20to%20wavelength%20jansky&source=bl&ots=IW4FpmnEIE&sig=6PdaCx7NtjPebUYCupYNGIjBVgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaxcvvgfjLAhVDWx4KHU78BcEQ6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q&f=true) (Using Si Units in Astronomy, Richard Dodd - Cambridge 2012) starting on page 27 and then there is an example on page 29.

Thanks Beta for looking into this!

Comment: That derivation looks very much like what I worked out, but when I used the "effective wavelength" listed in the table, my results did not match the values in the table. But at least now I know my approach wasn't all wrong.